# Is there any way to locate a variable in the exe and edit the value of the variable using C++?

Tags: c++

I'm in a situation that, I won't be able to decide the value of a variable in the early stages of the code. It needs to be patched in the exe for the release build. I have to locate a variable in the exe and change the value of the variable. Is there any way to do that? How to find the address of the location where the variable value is stored in the exe? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This is getting harder and harder to do (security concerns &c.). Plus many variables may well not end up being in the executable depending on compiler settings. For a "debug build", symbols will be in there somewhere.

Comment: @Bathasheba - Ok. What about adding value as a string table resource? Is it possible to update the value of it in the exe using BeginUpdateResource? I'm new to this. So I'm not sure if the logic itself is wrong or not.

Comment: If you are new to this topic maybe take a look: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhixgUqwRTjzzBeFSHXrw9DnQtssdAwgG really well explained guide for hacking. It also includes finding variables in exe and change them

Comment: My problem is, I won't be able to decide the value of a variable in the early stages of the code. It needs to be patched in the exe for the release build. So is it possible to store it as resource in the exe and patch it later?

Comment: @AcCoder while you can update resources, you would have to completely parse and regenerate the entire resource data from scratch, and you can't do that while the EXE is running

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I don't want to do it while exe is running. I can take the exe as input and change the value of the already entered sample string table value there. This logic is fine? Stringtable can be used to store values like checksum or any other data, right?

Comment: @AcCoder that is possible, but I think you are going about this all wrong. There are other ways to handle this during compile time without resorting to post-compile patching. But it would really help if you would [edit] your question to explain your actual situation in more detail.